# delete child node when root node is deleted - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm having a problem deleting child node. What I'm trying to do is that whenever a root node is deleted, it will also delete the child node. For example:

If I delete item 1, it should also delete item 2 automatically.

> id: 1, name: item 1, parent_id: 0
>
> id: 2, name: item 2, parent_d: 1

The id is PK and parent_id is FK.
I also created a sequence that when ever a new item is created, the id number increments by 1

sql command

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS note CASCADE;

CREATE SCHEMA note;

SET
search_path TO note;

CREATE TABLE note
(
    id           integer primary key,
    name         varchar(50),
    parent_id    integer  references note.note (id)             NOT NULL,
    created_at   timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE note_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE CACHE 1;
```

```
INSERT INTO note.note(id, name, parent_id) 

VALUES
 (1, 'item 1', 0)
,(2, 'item 2', 1)

SELECT SETVAL('note.note_id_seq',(SELECT MAX(id) FROM note.note))
```

Any suggestions would help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I really need help with this problem!

Comment: Your insert will not pass the foreign key constraint. What is the exact code you used?

Comment: The `NOT NULL` for the parent_id is a recipe for disaster. Do you really need it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `on delete cascade` to your foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE note
(
    id           integer primary key,
    name         varchar(50),
    parent_id    integer  references note (id)  on delete cascade NOT NULL,
    created_at   timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);
```

test it:

```
test=# insert into note(id,parent_id) values(0,0),(1,0),(2,1);
INSERT 0 3
test=# select (id,parent_id) from note;
  row  
-------
 (0,0)
 (1,0)
 (2,1)
(3 rows)

test=# delete from note where id = 1;
DELETE 1
test=# select (id,parent_id) from note;
  row  
-------
 (0,0)
(1 row)
```

Comment: I tried adding ```on delete cascade``` but it still doesn't work

Comment: So the things is I'm trying to start id number from 1, not 0.

Comment: Drop the `not null` and start with `1,null` or otherwise start with `1,1` . But be careful with recursive code in the latter case.